# How to get for a tag the list of users (in descending order) who get most upvotes (totally) for their answers related to this tag

Tags: support

How to get for a tag the list of users (in descending order) who get most upvotes (totally) for their answers related to this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the tag, and in the box at the top, click on the "top users" link.

```
http://the.SE.site.you.want/tags/tagname/topusers
```

Examples:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/topusers
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers

You'll get the 30 all-time top users, and the 30 top users in the last thirty days. (Your user is also always listed there so you can "rate" yourself.)